# The phrasal verb "factor in"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I encountered (probably) a multilingual Japanese saying

> Yes, that's what I was saying here. The XXXXX is itself a type of imperative, but the XXXXX doesn't factor into that sense.

The situation is, I was asking Japanese grammar. And XXXXX is Japanese so it is hidden.

Simply saying, does "factor in" mean "to (be) include/included to something"?

This is the best context I can give. I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you've check a dictionary, but I can see how this might confuse you even after you've looked up this phrasal verb. "Factor in" is usually found in the dictionaries defined as transitive. For instance, [Cambridge defines "factor in something"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/factor-in-something) as:

> to consider information, esp. as something that might influence a result:
> *It’s going to feel like 110° there when you factor in the humidity.*

However, this phrase is commonly used intransitively as well.<sup>1</sup> And yes it means "to be considered/included/figured in, be part of". Some examples:

> That type of attention may **factor into** why so many of the show's relationships have ultimately failed. (CNN)

> If Biden holds his current leads in Arizona, Michigan, Nevada, and Wisconsin, the Pennsylvania cases would not **factor into** the presidential election’s ultimate outcome. (The New Republic)

A couple other phrases share similar meanings. Personally, I am more likely to use "figure into" or "enter into" in these sentences.

<sup>1</sup> In Japanese grammar, it'd be 自動詞, except that in Japanese the transitivity binary comes in verb pairs, while in English a verb or phrasal verb can be both transitive and intransitive, depending on the context.